# GroupBy not working in .NET Core - same count in original and grouped list

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I'm working on project in .NET Core 3.1, but the version is not relevant for this question because I have a problem with [group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) with simple examples.

My original query is long, so when I was in process of creating the query, I wrote models which I used later in `select` and `group-by` for example:

```cs
public class GroupClass 
{ 
    public int PropA { get; set; }
}
```

I thought that problem is with joining results, but even a simple example with this model is not working:

```cs
int[] testArray = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
var result = (from a in testArray
              group a by new GroupClass
              {
                  PropA = a,
              } into g
              select new ModelClass
              {
                  PropA = g.Key.PropA,
              }).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

```
Result: 8 
Expected/wanted result: 3
```

Obviously, `group-by` failed to compare `3==3`, but what should I do? I have same problem with fluent syntax.

Here is the full code on rextester: [example](https://rextester.com/HVHJ22603).

Comment: What do you think is being used to compare in the `group`...`by`? C# is a language of types. What is the type? For that type, what does it mean to be equal?

Comment: @NetMage You are right, if you think that way about question, answer looks obvious. But when I saw bug I immediately tried to find something on SO without success, and I lost time. This is the reason I created this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are not defined (by default [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0) compares memory locations). One way to make this work is to use anonymous object:

```cs
group a by new
{
   PropA = a,
} into g
```

This works because CLR creates those methods for you, as stated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types)

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal.

Now to make it work with the model for `group-by`, you should implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

```cs
public class GroupClass
{
    public int PropA { get; set; }
    
    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if (o == null || GetType() != o.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        var other = o as GroupClassWorking;
        return this.PropA == other.PropA;
    }
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return PropA.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: How it is related to EF Core?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You are right, I should edit question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv But the example shown is for LINQ to Objects, so this answer is correct. We would need to see some LINQ to Database code to know what is going wrong with that. Also, where is EF Core mentioned?

Comment: @NetMage, because question is edited. And first title was about EF.